# Error when installing Lumen framework with Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

When I run

```
sudo composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0"
```

I get an error (below) that says it failed to download `elfet/php-ssh`.

```
Changed current directory to /Users/chad/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing elfet/php-ssh (v1.1.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...    Failed to download elfet/php-ssh from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/elfet/php-ssh/zipball/439becf180272542cbf154df4856a49dd3c4bf04" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
```

I am meeting all the server requirements too.  Any ideas why it's failing to install?

Answer (score 0):

It is a elfet/php-ssh package not found issue and it was resolved

Refer: https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/issues/158

Or you can install lumen via composer create-project and refer the following link has good tutorial about install lumen and create a simple rest api.

link: http://wsnippets.com/create-rest-api-using-lumen-micro-framework-by-laravel/